# How to load a lot of images in a web application?

Tags: php, image, http, loading, preloading

I am making a web application which uses loads of images. It's not something like a photo gallery. The web app is a kitchen planner. Users can place items in a room. And each item has a few images. Some items have multiple layers. So for example each layer is a seperate image.
But I also need to load some other data, like the z-index of an image, the name of the item, dimensions etc.
Images and the item data will be loaded by ajax calls.

I think of the following possibilities:

1. Loading each item as a json object, with the itemdata in that json object, and the image/gif data as base64 in the json object.
   Example:

```js
// GET Request: /item.php?id=123

{"id": "123", "name": "Granite table", "size": "...", "layers": 
    [
    {"img": "data:image/gif;base64,........", "depth": "0"},
    {"img": "data:image/gif;base64,........", "depth": "1"}
    ]
}
```

2. Loading item data (name, size, etc.) separate, and in that item data are also the image file names included. That image filenames can be used to load each gif image in a new request.

```js
// GET Request: /item.php?id=123

    {"id": "123", "name": "Granite table", "size": "...", "layers": 
        [
        {"img": "table-bottom.gif", "depth": "0"},
        {"img": "table-top.gif", "depth": "1"}
        ]
    }

// GET Request /images/table-bottom.gif
// GET Request /images/table-top.gif
```

The reason for this doubt is that I want to use as less data traffic as possible, but I also want to use less requests.

Comment: Maybe let users to upload zipped files and parse them on your server?

Comment: I think the 2nd version is better because in the 1st example, the client would have to wait until you process all images; turn them into base64 & send out a very large request at once which might takes too much time. the 2nd version however would return the data immediately & it's the browser's job to load the images, And I guess browser caching won't work with your 1st example so if a user visits the same page more than once, the 2nd example would be much faster.